# how prove $A_1$+$(-1)^nA_n$ is scalar matrix with following condition

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math

let $A_i\in M_n (\mathbb{R})$ ,$i=1,2,...,n$ 
$$A_1\cdot A_2 \cdot...\cdot A_n=I\hspace{5pt}\&\hspace{5pt}\det A_1=...=\det A_n=1$$ 
Assume that $A_1-A_k$  for $k=1,2,..,n-1$ are none zero and scalar matrix and that $A_k$ are distinct. How prove $A_1$+$(-1)^nA_n$ is a scalar matrix?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Source?${}{}{}$

Comment: this question is from shrif university contest math (2002)

Comment: Google has never heard of Shrif University. Could be Sharif University?

Comment: Perhaps you want to say ''$A_1-A_k$ for $k=\mathbf{2},\dots,n-1$  are none zero''.

Comment: Sharif university is popular university in Tehran (WWW.Sharif.Ir)sorry i answer late because i have exam tomorrow

Comment: yes$ A_1-A_k$for $k=\mathbf{2},\dots,n-1$ are none zero and  $A_1-A_k $ for for $k=\mathbf{2},\dots,n-1$are scalar

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(x) = \det(xI-A_1)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A$. By assumption, for $k=2,3,\ldots,n-1$, we have $A_1 - A_k = x_kI$ and $\det(A_k)=\det(A_1-x_kI)=1$ where $x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1}$ are nonzero distinct real numbers. So, if we define $x_1=0$, then $x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}$ must be distinct roots of $\det(A_1-xI)=1$. Let the remaining root of $\det(A_1-xI)=1$ be $x_n$. Then
$$
p(x)+(-1)^{n+1}=(-1)^n\left(\det(A_1-xI)-1\right)=(x-x_1)\ldots(x-x_n).
$$
Therefore, by Cayley-Hamilton theorem,
$$
(-1)^{n+1}I = (A_1-x_1)\ldots(A_1-x_{n-1}I)(A_1-x_nI)
= A_1\ldots A_{n-1}(A_1-x_nI).
$$
However, by assumption, $A_1\ldots A_{n-1}A_n=I$. Hence $A_n=(-1)^{n+1}(A-x_nI)$ and $A_1+(-1)^nA_n=x_nI$ is a scalar matrix.